# How to save the text from rich text editor into the database .I am using MVC application and have downloaded the editor from NUGET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rich-text-editor

How to save the text from **rich text editor** into the database ?
I am using MVC application and have downloaded the editor from NUGET.

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: I have tried to add the following code   Editor Editor1 = new Editor(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, "Editor1");
            Editor1.LoadFormData("Type here...");
            Editor1.MvcInit();
            ViewBag.Editor = Editor1.MvcGetString(); to the controller